# why my @autowired doesn't work

Tags: spring

Recently I got a problem when trying to start up an existing server. It seems one of field ABCManager didn't been autowired by spring bean factory. This has been added - "context:anotation-config" into config file. 
I checked code change version, ABCManager only have a private constructor method (before it has a getInstance method). Does this matter? Will Spring using private constructor to get an instance for me or this is why I got an NPE?
If this is not, what else I should check?

Comment: Can you add your application config and exception you get and post it in your question?

Comment: I finally get what's going on there after debugging this issue. That's still a configuration issue, some dependency beans are not config in *.xml.

Answer (score 0):

are you class  annotated?
your class must be annotated with `@Component` or `@Service` or `@Repository`

Answer (score 0):

As this been uses a static method to get an instance, Spring doesn't know it by default.
You will have to specify your static method in the bean deceleration.

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean2" factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

Your factory-method will be your static method used to instantiate this bean.

Comment: No, I debug codes to find even you didn't provide public constructor, spring still generate a instance for me. So if you don't provide a factory method, that's also fine.